# Android Studio - google maps v2 does not work after format my notebook

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-2

I create an app using Android Studio 1.5 and Google Maps v2 and it works fine. How imagine was created a fingerprint SHA1 and put de app on app store. Recently I have to format my notebook and now the maps doesn't work!!

I install Android Studio 1.5 and 2.1 but continue dont working!! Someone have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After work hard, I find the solution:

First Step

1) first verify if Google Play Services is installed

2) Click Menu tools -> Android -> SDK Manager

3) Select System Settings -> Android SDK

4) In the right, click in SDK Tools pane

5) Mark "Google Play  services"

Second Step

1) Run (windows) on bash: keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

For Linux is the same, but put the correct debug.keystore path!

This is will work in develop enviorment!